# How to calculate TPR and TNR

Tags: r, r-caret

I need to find the TPR and TNR for probability cut-offs of (i) p = 0.3; (ii) p = 0.7, for optimal models of logistic regression and trees. I have no idea how to do this, and any help would be appreciated!

This is my code for logistic regression and trees:

```
library(caret) 

tr.ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10,
repeats = 5,
summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, 
classProbs = TRUE,
)

set.seed(150847)
glm.fit <- train(Class ~ ., data = train.dat,
          trControl = tr.ctrl,
          method = "glm", family = "binomial", 
        preProcess = c("center", "scale"))

glm.fit$results [ row.names(glm.fit$bestTune),]


set.seed(150847)
tree.fit <- train(Class ~ ., data = train.dat
, trControl = tr.ctrl
, method = "rpart" 
, preProcess = c("center", "scale")
, tuneGrid = expand.grid(cp = seq(.00001, 1, length.out = 100 ) )
)

tree.fit$bestTune
```

My data train.dat:

```
structure(list(x1 = c(-2.48941991263215, -0.338448010439568, 
-1.07796826066294, 1.47833943928667, -0.19013864138727, 0.708635458099694, 
-1.23724847469945, -0.563757474548103, 0.845604758116324, -0.205849502281457
), x2 = c(-1.05660014431803, -1.75938416652951, -1.94445363537753, 
2.65603302304451, -0.818464313993987, 0.671670710096937, -1.73906216686269, 
-0.32993091478973, -0.00212755901980971, 1.39754416931398), x3 = c(-0.928819609794076, 
-0.24431689960579, -0.26055539595143, -0.500006066823682, 0.19947842697796, 
-0.023029991245775, -0.186262810403301, -1.42546338933162, 0.00122988996266972, 
-1.28855224962409), x4 = c(0.167674885884102, -0.714651010370962, 
0.501841366660604, -0.261356553409404, -0.121081806911108, -1.04211559643584, 
-0.50492946793311, -1.19773545239521, 0.73763127841244, -0.540732699677932
), x5 = c(0.826293680351228, -0.0522530856542289, 0.456970179919153, 
-0.483860304113477, 0.827117071952671, 0.918654521461576, -0.0503890146501362, 
0.308007133658975, 0.570045402739197, -0.931803230196238), x6 = c(0.229410925647244, 
0.367363323224708, 0.0097867208532989, 0.6599692159798, 0.454895325470716, 
0.559888116084039, 0.918430505087599, 0.835628909757361, 0.449318847851828, 
0.4865414169617), x7 = c(0.277445634594187, 0.00411403737962246, 
0.912381467409432, 0.0911673668306321, 0.0729619956109673, 0.25802564015612, 
0.408150271046907, 0.429482856066898, 0.420060770353302, 0.361429972341284
), x8 = c(0.403632419444111, -1.76177968998027, 0.818339220424296, 
0.77257524859948, -1.45634200383022, 1.29017046323978, 0.408054990932775, 
-1.20476324065398, 0.690360006550585, -0.969127060729179), x9 = c(0.666298305218494, 
1.28068782733132, 0.243489971387096, 0.00907678612957343, 0.0688231437305274, 
0.326917875030205, 0.669331007931665, -1.14748576899504, 0.41743119655274, 
-1.45865799172868), x10 = c(-0.674113519037765, -0.221583500325269, 
0.555570222138564, 0.572105515491289, 2.32224808146226, 0.807037729170473, 
-0.0970994017567565, 1.39240819044007, -0.830851187122677, -0.131544556958435
), x11 = c(-0.503906052691753, -0.170463238913734, 1.81239693119702, 
-0.310259330876175, 0.373355276436323, -0.390595837065986, 0.291024469135808, 
0.874233233255899, -0.727173808933225, -0.674768027329343), x12 = c(0.569346066655445, 
0.665270271264321, -1.04590277174209, -1.08749423169221, -0.717326819631265, 
-1.04416447772937, -0.56732093661245, -0.352233144887394, -0.544294051590876, 
-1.46441415892515), Class = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your data is not seems to be right, you have NAs in your Class variable, Please fix it first. also write all the libraries which you are using in your case you are using caret, so please mention it as well,Thanks

Comment: Hello Kumar, thank you for the feedback. I have edited my post! :)

Comment: what is tr.ctrl object?

Comment: Sorry! I have added in the code for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

With your data and the code, you posted I get an error in fitting the logistic model ("Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing:... Error: Stopping") and a warning (prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading). Check carefully your data or provide a dummy example for your issue. However, the TPR and TNR are synonymous for sensitivity and specificity, which you can extract from the output of `caret::confusionMatrix`. To use the cutoff 0.3/0.7 you can do something like:

```
x <- predict(glm.fit,train.dat$class,type="prob")
pred <- as.factor(ifelse(x$No>0.3,"No","Yes"))
cm <- confusionMatrix(pred,as.factor(train.dat$Class))
cm$byClass[c("Sensitivity","Specificity")]
```

if you have a test set you can substitute `train.dat$class` with `test.dat$class` in the first line. For a more detailed answer please provide a correct example data